# VBA InputBox default value un-selection

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I am using InputBox in Excel to get a simple yes or no answer from the user which I will later use for a formula to give extra information.
InputBox (actually 9 in succesion) is activated when clicked on a specific cell. Each InputBox is prefilled with sequence number (1, 2, 3 ...) that I will use for my formula.
Problem I have is that the InputBox prefilled number is selected (see picture), so if a user starts to type, number is deleted and only the answer is left. Solution would be for the user to do a mouse click to unselect the number but this is just an extra step I don't want. Also if the user is not careful, the number might not get filled and formula won't work.
Any suggestions how to get this corrected?
[image]

Comment: You are going down a road which is highly not recommended! :) I would recommend using a customized userform with comboboxes for Yes/No. Also 1 form can be used multiple times.

Comment: But you know which sequence number is relevant when you popup, and get the answer. Why do you have to show it in the input field at all?

Comment: I need the sequence number so that I have something to search for with formula. Each number will have extra information added to it later.
Result will look like: 1. Y 2. N 3. Y and so on. Some Y or N answers will need extra comments by user, so I can't just search for Y or N in the array of text.

Comment: But userform seems like a much simpler choice, thanks!